# Await multiple ajax calls inside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await

Context: Making an ajax heavy page that changes values in different selectors based on what prior selectors have chosen. Working on making a "repopulate" option based on prior entries.

When selector 1 is changed, an ajax call is made that populates both selector 2 and 3. Selector 1's options never change.

---

When you "repopulate" from a prior entry, the code starts by changing selector 1's value and then activates a change event on selector 1.

```
function repopulateFromEntry(event)  {
    // We want the children of the parent TR.
    // <tr>
    //  <td>...</td>
    //  ...
    //  <td><button></td>
    // <tr>
    let td_list = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children;

    $('#selector1').val(td_list[0].innerHTML);
    $('#selector1').change();
    // Do other things that rely on prior to be finished
    // Problem is here.
};
```

Selector 1's change event looks like this.

```
async function executeAjax(url, success) {
    return await $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: success
    });
}

$('#selector1').change(async function(e) {
    await executeAjax('api/selector2' + $("#selector1").val(), function() {
        // Set selector2 from ajax data
    });
    await executeAjax('api/selector3' + $("#selector1").val(), function() {
        // Set selector3 from ajax data
    });
});
```

After the selectors options are set based on selector1's value, it then goes in and selects the correct value for selectors 2 and 3.

---

My problem is that the reselection of values for selectors 2 and 3 is getting called before the options are fully populated to the selectors, making the reselection fail.

I'm clearly missing something from the async/await/ajax section to keep it from continuing without both calls being done, but I can't seem to see what my issue is.

Comment: You should remove the callback parameter from your `executeAjax` function. Use promise chaining instead!

Comment: "*the reselection of values for selectors 2 and 3*" - where's the code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I used async/await for the $.ajax call,  and then in your change event handler, I used .then method to act on the resulting data.  (Also could have used async await in the event handler, but since you had that originally and it wasn't working I opted for promise instead).

I'm pretty sure this should work, but if not, please let me know what the console is showing.

**NOTE**  You may need to console.log result and pull out the data you are looking for before setting the value of each selector.  You can do that inside the .then method.

```
async function executeAjax(url) {

    let result;

    try { 
        result = await $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET"
        });

        return result;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

$('#selector1').change(function(e) {

    executeAjax('api/selector2' + $("#selector1").val())
    .then((result) => { 
        // console.log(result);  <-- may need to find and pull the data you are looking for out of result
        // let myVal = result[?]['something'].orother;
        $("#selector2").val(result); 
    });

    executeAjax('api/selector3' + $("#selector1").val())
    .then((result) => {
        // console.log(result);  <-- may need to find and pull the data you are looking for out of result
        // let myVal = result[?]['something'].orother;
        $("#selector3").val(result);
    });

});
```

Comment: Same thing happens. It tries to execute the code further down the line before the ajax is finished populating selector 2 and 3.

Comment: @NicholasSteichen OK, I updated answer, this should work.

Comment: I actually came up with that before you fixed it - still marking as correct value. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NicholasSteichen Glad you got it working.  Cheers!